# Use single sign-on username in Web AppBuilder filter widget?

Tags: query, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, authentication, widget

I have an Portal web map:

[image]

Details:

- The map has a Web AppBuilder [filter widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-filter.htm)
- It uses [single sign-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) (SSO) authentication

---

The map has a work order layer that is integrated from a Workorder Management System (WMS). Each work order record in the layer has a work order `username` value (example: JDOE).

I would like to configure the map so that it:

1. Grabs the SSO username that it used to authenticate the web map
2. **Filters** the work orders based on the **username**

**Is it possible do this--to filter the layer based on the SSO username?**

Comment: I think you'll need to use the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to do this but I don't work with that and I've only had a quick dabble with the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder.

Comment: You may also want to look at the ArcGIS Workflow Manager for Server: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/workflow-manager/latest/help/what-is-workflow-manager-for-server.htm

Comment: @user1973 Did you get this to function with the answer below? I was just curious because I really need something like this to work, but I haven't had success

Comment: @GravitaZ If you provide a way for me to contact you, I can refer you to the developer who came up with the solution in the answer. Unfortunately, I haven't had a chance to implement/test it.

Comment: @GravitaZ Oh, it looks like you found a solution: [Grabbing the portal sign-on Username in WebAppBuilder and filtering records based on the user logged in](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353596/grabbing-the-portal-sign-on-username-in-webappbuilder-and-filtering-records-base)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to build an attribute expression in the Filter widget:

[image]

So basically: `<<YOUR_USERNAME_FIELD>>` is `*USERNAME*`

The custom code below will replace `*USERNAME*` with the currently logged in user's username.

You will need to alter two of the functions in `Filter/Widget.js`.

These lines in `PostCreate()` will get the current Portal username:

```
this.portal = portalUtils.getPortal(this.appConfig.portalUrl);
this.username = this.portal.user.username;
```

This 'if' statement in `_getExpr()` will replace `*USERNAME*` in the filter expression with the username.

```
if(expr.indexOf('*USERNAME*') !== -1)
{
  expr = expr.replace('*USERNAME*',this.username);
}
```