# Grabbing the portal sign-on Username in WebAppBuilder and filtering records based on the user logged in

Tags: filter, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

We have Arcgis Portal 10.7.1 set up with WebAppbuilder 2.51  Users sign in using their Enterprise logins.
We also have a large Feature Service dataset (over 1 million records) with multiple account managers and one of the fields contains their login usernames.

We were trying to implement a way to be able to pull their portal usernames into possibly the filter Widget and filter the dataset based on which user is logged in.

I already did a search of StackExchange and found this article, but we could not implement it to function properly.
[Use single sign-on username in Web AppBuilder filter widget?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336693/use-single-sign-on-username-in-web-appbuilder-filter-widget/337725#337725)

I was hoping that someone else has run into this and implemented a possible solution, even if it is not using the Filter widget.

To be specific, I am getting the error when implementing the code in the link above, and receiving this error, although I followed all the instructions.

```
Cannot read property 'getPortal' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by basically putting all the code in the _getExpr: section of the Filter Widget.

```
_getExpr: function(layerId,username) {
        //var portal = new esri.arcgis.Portal('https://segramapsdev.lumosnet.com/portal/')
        //var userName = esri.arcgis.PortalUser(this.username);

        this.portal = portalUtils.getPortal(this.appConfig.portalUrl);  
        username = this.portal.user.username;  

         if (!this._store[layerId]) {
          return null;
        }

        var parts = [];
        var exprs = this._store[layerId];

        for (var p in exprs) {
          var expr = exprs[p];
          if(expr.toString().indexOf('*USERNAME*') !== -1)
            {
            expr = expr.replace('*USERNAME*', username);
            }
          if (expr && p !== 'mapFilterControls') {
            parts.push('(' + expr + ')');           
          }

        }
```

Comment: Where is the Filter Widget code located (folder/path location) in order to make this edit?